# Using Awk or sed, how to pull last item in the list?

Tags: awk, sed

In the below, I need to fetch the last item `"subnet-0bfc68cb13432a94b"` with double quotes with use of Awk or sed?

```
[
    "subnet-08585db3344bce1ea",
    "subnet-0537a333d2337f361",
    "subnet-0bfc68cb13432a94b"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'"' '/"$/{print $2}' file
subnet-0bfc68cb13432a94b
```

or any sed:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*"\(.*\)"$/\1/p' file
subnet-0bfc68cb13432a94b
```

Comment: thanks for this ..one correction if i want it in double quotes,,,,what needs to be done ??

Comment: Accept an answer to the question you asked (`i need to fetch the last item subnet-0bfc68cb13432a94b with out double quotes`) and then ask a new question as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged.

Comment: "SubnetId": "subnet-05ce5r3fee502de7e9" how to fetch the value - subnet-05ce5r3fee502de7e9 using awk or sed ?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse JSON:

```
jq -r '.[-1]' file.json
```

Example:

```
$ cat << EOF | jq -r '.[-1]'
[
    "subnet-08585db3344bce1ea",
    "subnet-0537a333d2337f361",
    "subnet-0bfc68cb13432a94b" 
]
EOF
subnet-0bfc68cb13432a94b
```

Comment: This is output of command and it has to further passed on to another command in bash script. so awk or sed will better help on this matter

Comment: How so? You can pipe to and from `jq`. `cmd1 | jq ... | cmd3`?

Comment: It's one thing if don't want to add `jq` dependency, but the answer is fully valid and can easily be piped further. :)

Comment: yes @KaffeMyers dont have jq installed so would be possible other way?

Comment: Sure, see my alternative answer

Answer (score 1):

```sh
read -r -d '' content <<EOF
[
    "subnet-08585db3344bce1ea",
    "subnet-0537a333d2337f361",
    "subnet-0bfc68cb13432a94b" 
]
EOF

awk -F'"' '($2){o=$2} END{print o}' <<<"$content"

### output
subnet-0bfc68cb13432a94b
```

So, assuming there is no other information passed along, this should be an easy sollution.

Basically:

- set field separator to `double-qoutes`
- store/overwrite value in a variable
- output variable by the end, now containing the last element of that array.

---

A sed solution taking advantage of the last element not having a comma could look like this:

```sh
sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*"\(.*\)"[[:space:]]*$/\1/p' <<<$content
```

So:

- Suppress normal output with `-n` flag
- Capture the content within the double-quotes and print it

Comment: one correction....I want it to return as "subnet-0bfc68cb13432a94b"  (in double quotes) in that case how it has to be awk solution ?

Comment: for the sed, just move the paranthesis to include the double-quotes

Comment: Or a simpler awk `awk '/"$/ {print $1}'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 'N;$!D;s/.*"(.*)".*/\1/p' file
```

Capture the last two lines and then using pattern matching return the required string.

Alternative:

```
sed -E '$!{h;d};g;s/.*"(.*)".*/\1/' file
```